# Laravel incoporating a count in a DB query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, properties and photos with a basic code of

```
  $pr = DB::table('properties')
->leftJoin('photos', 'properties.id', '=', 'photos.property_id')
->select(['properties.id', 'address', 'town', 'postcode', 'units','unitType','examination','priority','completed','quotationRequired']);
```

I would like to count the number of photos to each property and incorporate it into the select as something like noPhotos.

I seem to be stuck on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
  $pr = DB::table('properties')->leftJoin('photos', 'properties.id', '=', 'photos.property_id')->select(DB::raw('count(photos.id) as photos_count'))->addSelect(['properties.id', 'address', 'town', 'postcode', 'units','unitType','examination','priority','completed','quotationRequired'])->groupBy('properties.id', 'address', 'town', 'postcode', 'units','unitType','examination','priority','completed','quotationRequired')->get();
```